# unable to translate text using gettext in zend framework 2

Tags: php, internationalization, zend-framework2, gettext

I'm beginner in Zend framework 2. I'm facing problem with translation in zf2.
I have downloaded a sample **zend skeleton application**. and edited en_US.po file using PO editor, and change "Home" to "testing" and saved. And en_US.mo file created successfully.

Now my intention is to show "testing" instead of "Home" in menu item.So i added the following code in module.config.php.

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',

        ),
```

And in layout.phtml `<?php echo $this->translate('Home') ?>`

But I'm not getting the text i wanted.Am i missing some thing? Please let me know.
Is there any good tutorial about internationalization in zf2?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you edited en_US.po and changed "Home" to "testing", do you mean that you added the translation "testing" to the source "Home"?

If you just changed it, then it will not be looking for "Home" at all.

Comment: Finally,I got it. I have to use "translation_file_patterns" instead of "translation_patterns". And it works fine. Anyway thank you Ajaypayne.